# AJAX com retorno de dados em HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

Tenho uma função *AJAX*:

```
function userCheck() {
    var username = $("#username").html();
    var userid = $("#balmung-id").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "systems/usercheck.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            username: username,
            userid: userid
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loaderror").hide();
            $("#loader").show();
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#loader").hide();
            $("#user-painel-2").html(result);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#loader").hide();
            $("#loaderror").show();
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });
}
```

Ela envia dados e o retorno é feito através de um `echo` no *PHP*:

```
echo '<div id="userReturn">"'.$valor.'"</div>';
```

Essa `div` vai ser inserida dentro de um menu, como especificado no `result` do *AJAX*:

```
success: function(result) {
                $("#loader").hide();
                $("#user-painel-2").html(result);
            }
```

Eu devo usar o retorno sempre em *JSON*, ou posso continuar fazendo dessa forma sem problemas? Qual a diferença entre usar o retorno de dados em *JSON* e não *HTML*?

Comment: JSON são dados estruturados de uma forma diferente. Retornar como você está retornando é em formato HTML. Se você retornar em JSON fica complicado você retornar o HTML nele. Da forma como você está fazendo está certo.

Comment: Eu tenho um sistema aqui que eu retorno uma página no AJAX.

Comment: Na verdade não há praticamente dificuldade nenhuma em transformar um json em html @Gumball ele pode manipular o json como quiser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSON é um formato padronizado de estruturação de dados, assim como o XML. Usar ele favorece a interoperabilidade e também a reusabilidade.

Supondo que você tenha esse retorno em JSON, você pode usar ele em várias páginas e em diferentes estruturas de marcação, bastando que você trate esse JSON e faça o que quiser com ele. O retorno direto em HTML te engessa nesse sentido, e você não vai ter muita liberdade de tratar esses dados quando eles chegarem às suas páginas.

Em suma, o JSON permite maior flexibilidade, mas vem ao custo de ter que tratar os dados. O HTML é menos flexível, mas é mais prático, já vem pronto pra uso.

Eu, particularmente, prefiro ter flexibilidade, por isso tenho preferência pelos retornos em JSON (ou XML).

Comment: Outro aspeto que pode valer a pena referires é que um dia quando o front-end da app fôr redesenhado pode implicar mexer no código do servidor. Enquanto que se vier JSON o novo front-end pode utilizar isso. `+1`

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente você ta dando retorno em dados desnecessários quando faz o retorno diretamente com o HTML pronto, vamos imaginar um cenário onde o seu retorno tenha aproximadamente 1000 linhas como esta:

```
<div id="userReturn">"'.$valor.'"</div>
```

Esse echo seria repetido 1000x o que faria com que o retorno ficasse mais pesado pois o mesmo está transportando mais dados.

Se você fizer o retorno em JSON você estaria retornando apenas os valores a serem adicionados na div, logo você estaria transferindo menos dados, e a resposta para sua requisição seria mais rápida e não irá exigir muito do servidor, uma vez que você recebe esses valores com o JS você pode processar e criar as divs dentro de um loop. Você terá o mesmo conteúdo sendo servido mais rápido e irá melhorar o desempenho da sua aplicação e consumir menos dados. Usando JSON você poderá manipular esses dados da forma que quiser logo, se quiser armazená-lo para usar em diferentes funções também e em diferentes páginas você consegue, se fizer o retorno em HTML você ficará limitado.

Se for apenas para um retorno de dados simples de poucas linhas não vejo grandes problemas em usar o retorno direto como texto HTML, mas se for para uma aplicação grande com grandes quantidade de linhas recomendo o uso de JSON

Answer (score 0):

Bem, na verdade o que você está retornando é um texto e depois o navegador vai entender que é html. Eu não sei o propósito do seu retorno, se é apenas para mostrar um valor, ou algo parecido. O mais normal(certo) é que você sempre volte em JSON, depois transforme esse texto em JSON em um objeto e faça o que você deseja. 
A diferença é que JSON é algo certo a se fazer, por que foi feito para retorno de dados, e html não. 
Se você quer retornar o valor dentro dessa div, deixe a div em hide dentro do user-painel-2, e quando der o success, você coloca o resultado dentro da div e mande ela aparecer.