# Atualizar campo com dados do select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Tenho um campo do tipo select que seleciono um motorista, gostaria que quando eu selecionasse esse motorista o campo de texto recebesse o telefone desse motorista, que já vem com a informação da linha do select!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Motorista:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon icone-input">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                </div>
                <select id="select-motorista-ex" id="f_rec_analist_fiscal" name="f_rec_analist_fiscal" style="width: 100%">
                    <option value='1'>Selecione um parceiro</option>
                    @foreach($parceiros as $p)
                    <option value='{{$p->parc_cpf_cnpj}}'>{{$p->parc_razao_social}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Contato</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon icone-input">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="f_rec_motor_tel" id="f_rec_motor_tel" value="{{ old('f_rec_motor_tel') }}" class="form-control" maxlength="15" placeholder="(XX) XXXXX-XXXX">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me auxiliar, pois não entendi bem o ajax ainda!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [AJAX com retorno de dados em HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172992/ajax-com-retorno-de-dados-em-html)

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue faz isso com ajax, vou mostrar um exemplo bem prático e simples para entender.

Criei um select com os motoristas, nos options coloquei o id do motorista e um input para receber o telefone,

```
<select id="select-motorista-ex">
    <option value="1"> Motorista 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Motorista 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Motorista 3</option>
</select>
<input type="tel" id="telefone">
```

No javascript usei a função [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/), ela é executada quando há alguma alteração no elemento, quando altera o select do motorista é executada a função e faz um requisição no php via post,

```
$("#select-motorista-ex").on("change", function(){
    var motorista = $(this).val();
    $.post("motorista.php", {motorista: motorista}, function( data ) {
        $("#telefone").val(data);
    });
});
```

Já o PHP será responsável por receber o parâmetro pego no value do select e enviar via post do ajax, dentro do php é possível realizar um consulta na base de dados, criei um array bem simples para obter algum resultado,

```
// array com os telefones de acordo com o id
$arrayMotorista =   [
                        1 => 99999999,
                        2 => 88888888,
                        3 => 77777777,
                    ];
// id do motorista selecionado no select
$motorista = $_POST['motorista'];
// resposta com o telefone do motorista
echo $arrayMotorista[$motorista];
```

**Complemento:**

Notando que você usa o Laravel, é bom ressaltar alguns pontos.

**1. Token**

Isso destina-se mais especificamente a formulários do tipo `AJAX`. É basicamente pegar o `token` e incluí-lo nos cabeçalhos para quando você enviar uma solicitação via `AJAX`.

Além de verificar o `token CSRF` como um parâmetro `POST`, o `middleware` `VerifyCsrfToken` também verifica o cabeçalho da solicitação (`X-CSRF-TOKEN`). Por isso a existência dessa `metatag`.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Então, uma vez que se criou a `metatag`, você pode instruir uma biblioteca como `jQuery` para adicionar automaticamente o `token` a todos os cabeçalhos de solicitação. Isso fornece proteção `CSRF` simples e conveniente para suas aplicações baseadas em `AJAX`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

**2. Rota**

Você precisará definir uma rota (e claro criar uma função no `Controller`) para esta chamada.

```
Route::post('ajaxBusca', ['as' => 'ajax.busca', 'uses' => 'Ajax@BuscaAlgo']);
```

E claro, adicioná-la na chamada.

```
...
$.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('ajax.busca') }}",
    data: {
        'motorista': 'dado referencia motorista'
    },   
...
```

**3. Tratamento no Controller**

Como qualquer fomulario manipulado no `Laravel`, você precisa tratar os dados recebidos e enviar o json de resposta.

```
public function BuscarAlgo(Request $request)
{
    $dados = $request->all(); // ou
    $dados = $request->except('_token');
    ......
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Eu já tenho a informação na view no array $parceiros, mesmo assim eu preciso fazer uma outra consulta ou eu consigo alterar o campo conforme a id dele e que é $p->parc_cpf_cnpj dentro do array e a informação que preciso que está em $p->parc_tel_comercial.